# How many incoming VPN connections can Windows Small Business User 2011 handle?

Tags: windows, vpn

I have three Windows 7 laptops I was to use to set up a network for my business. I was planning to make one the server and have other two connect remotely through the VPN service. I understand that Windows 7 only allows one VPN connection at a time, so I'll have to get a different OS.

I was looking at Windows Small Business Server 2011, but I don't want to take the plunge until I know that it can support multiple incoming VPN connections. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well not much sure about the SBS 2011 with multiple connection but i have been using Windows Server 2008 R2 which allows me to work with multiple connections at the same time and the speed and working capacity is with according to my need. I am also searching around to find something related to SBS 2011 with vpn but couldn't get much information about the multiple connectivity. I have been using Purevpn server from last couple of months for months to engage my work area with vpn and the experience is quiet good to me. They offer this VPN Server facility via WS 2008 R8. 
I think you better need to contact with Microsoft team they can guide you better about SBS 2011 with multiple connections.
I hope that my input may result is some good signs for you.Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

My company use SBS 2011 with VPN fine - I don't think there's a specifically enforced limit on the number of VPN users (though of course you'll need enough CAL licenses to cover you).

Comment: Oh, to clarify, we have at least 15 VPN users, and it works fine.